# Excel VBA .Trim function changes . to ,

Tags: excel, vba, trim

Earlier today I was cleaning up data, using the .trim() vba function. Though it caused . to be changed to , and I have no idea why.

```
Cells(rw, j).Value = Trim(Cells(rw, j).Value)
```

Is all I did, and it changed values as follows:

5.2  -> 5,2

One might think that is due to the local settings, though the same column contains values like 3(6.1) which are not messed up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to use `Cells(rw, j).Value = Trim(Cells(rw, j))`

Comment: What is the `.NumberFormat` for that cell?

Comment: I'd bet my house that's local settings. The reason `3(6.1)` retains a decimal point is that, I'm pretty sure, this value will be interpreted as a String.

Comment: Not sure what you refer to by the numberformat, but when loaded (which is also done by a script) they're all formatted perfectly. Aftrer using the .trim function they are messed up. I want them to be interpreted as a string and I just want the trailing spaces to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to File - Options - Advanced and look for **Use system separators**. You want the decimal separator to be . and the Thousands separator to be ,

You can also change these in VBA using the following code:

```
 Application.DecimalSeparator = "." 
 Application.ThousandsSeparator = "," 
 Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
```

As you don't want to changes these setting, change your code to:

```
Cells(rw, j).Value = "'" & Trim(Cells(rw, j).Text)
```

.Text will give you the string version of what is in the cell rather than attempt to convert it to a number (if it looks like a number).

Comment: Thats the thing, my decimal separator is a comma, though this column needs to be interpreted as a string.

Comment: Error still holds, even with the second solution.

Comment: I have concatenated a single quote on to the front of your string to tell Excel to process it as a string. It works on my version of Excel.

Comment: or `Format$(Trim$(Cells(rw, j).Text), "@")`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your global system/excel settings for this one application, you could try forcing the value to text with something like:

```
With Cells(rw, j)
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = Trim(Cells(rw, j).Value)
End With
```

Alternatively, based on your comment:

```
With Cells(rw, j).Value = "'" & Trim(Cells(rw, j).Value)
```

Comment: Applied to NumberFormat to the entire column, no luck.

Comment: Added another suggestion.

Comment: Still no luck. Been on this for 2 hours now and it is getting on my nerves.

Comment: I hate to copy the value of the cell contents of the considered column, after that the same error appeared again. I ended up using NumberFormat.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Dim temp As String
temp = Cells(rw, j).Value
temp = Trim(temp)
Cells(rw, j).Value = temp
```

Unfortunately I can't test it.